# How to double ssh in bash using a private key and different users

Tags: ssh

In order for me to ssh to B, I need to go through A.

```
Host A
  HostName x.x.x.x
  User user
  IdentityFile ~/pathto/file.pem

Host B
  ProxyCommand ssh A -A nc x.x.x.x 22
```

I just tried ProxyCommand and nc based from searches I made but nc fails. The reason for that one is in order to ssh to B I need to set the user which is different from the user in A. nc only accepts host and port. Is there a way to do it using nc or i need to use another command? If its another command can you tell me what command i need to use?

Comment: Using `nc` for this has not been necessary for many years. You can just write `ProxyCommand -W %h:%p A`. And if you have a recent `ssh` version it will be even simpler to just write `ProxyJump A`. Moreover using `-A` like that is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a stupid mistake, I did not add the User field in the Host B. I thought i need to specify the User in the command not in the Host.